# Wrong parallel with gfortran compiled by -fopenmp wth specified threads

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I wrote a simple code to test the correctness of parallelism.
The subroutine to be called is

```
SUBROUTINE two_pt_fn()
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: i,j
!$OMP PARALLEL DO
DO i=1,10
j=i*2
WRITE(*,*)i,j
END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
END SUBROUTINE
```

The main program simply calls the above subroutine, and
the source codes are compiled by

```
gfortran -fopenmp -o m.x sb_two_pt_fn.f90  main.f90
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=10
```

The result of running

```
./m.x
```

gives

> ```
>        7          20
>        8          16
>        9          18
>        1          18
>        2           4
>       10           6
>        4           6
>        5          10
>        6          12
>        3          12
> ```

It's simply multiply the loop index i by 2 but 
the result is not correct for every i. Only a few of them are correct.

Why?? I am new to parallel computing with fortran. Besides the answer, nice tutorial document for parallel that includes more complete concept teaching would be very helpful.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your openmp section misses the "private" clause for j. i, being the loop variable, is private by default.

As j is not private, several threads will attempt to use use (set its value or use it for printing) at the same time and this leads to inconsistent results.

Solution: add `PRIVATE(i,j)` at the end of the line `!$OMP PARALLEL DO`

Comment: I think I've had instances where I get complaints if trying to make the loop variable explicitly private as it's is implicitly so. I could be remembering wrongly, but `PRIVATE(j)` should be enough anyway.

Comment: It should be enough but I prefer to make it explicit in general. I never had any error with either gfortran or ifort with this procedure.